# mobaxterm popup mode

Tags: администрирование

Доброго времени суток всем!
Вопрос тем, кто пользовался терминалом Mobaxterm для виндоус.
Там есть удобный попап режим (по Ctrl + Alt + M).
Так же там есть там вкладка Session, где я могу сохранять подключения (ssh например), и в дальнейшем быстро подключаться кликнув по закладке.
Вопрос - как использовать сохранённые сессии в попап режиме? Может кто то разгадал эту загадку.
Всем заранее спасибо.